# Recursive Include Paths in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I'm new to using Visual Studio and I'm trying to create a project to compile my existing program. The program already is compiling on macOS using Xcode. The folder structure of the project looks like this:

```
main folder
  src
    some code here
    Debug
      some code here
    Utility
      some code here
      Special Utility Folder
    Rendering
      some code here
      Rendering Utils
...
```

When I tried to load the project up into Visual Studio, I got a lot of errors saying that the header files could not be found. I did some investigation and it seems like the include paths are not recursive. So to include a file from src/Utility I would have to write

```
#include "Utility/header.hpp"
```

But all of the code in the project uses includes like

```
#include "header.hpp"
```

Is there a way to get this to work in visual studio?

P.s. manually adding all of the folders as their own include paths works, but it will be a pain to maintain as the project grows, especially since majority of my work will be done in Xcode

Comment: Include paths are not recursive for _any_ C++ compiler I'm aware of.

Comment: Danged if I know why that works under X-Code. They're probably doing something "helpful" out of sight.

Comment: @user4581301 that was my guess

Answer (score 1):

You can set the include paths for all the folders(it is not recursive) in the project properties:

To access the project configuration:

1. Right-click on the project, and select Properties.
2. Select Configuration Properties->C/C++->General.
3. Set the path under Additional Include Directories:
   i.e.: `.` `Debug` `Utility` etc..

Maybe you can also use a cmd tool to create the includes path in a txt file(i.e.: IncludePath.txt). 
Inside that file you can add the include folders:

```
/I "."
/I ".."
/I ".\Debug"
/I ".\Utility"
```

Then set the path under Additional Include Directories:

```
@IncludePath.txt
```

Comment: Manually adding each and every path does work, as I stated in the original question, but I was looking for perhaps a more elegant solution

Comment: Does the IncludePath.txt workaround actually work (VS 2015)? I can not find any documentation about it...

Comment: I know it's old but I ran across this and thought I'd say:  yes it does work.  You can use "cl @<filename>" to submit a file of command-line options to the CL compiler, as described here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-command-files?view=vs-2019

Comment: ...and while this works for any command-line switch, as Rama suggests, it's a good way to encapsulate numerous "/I" include directory directives.  So per Rama's example, you could also add "@IncludePath.txt" to: Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line > Additional Options