# Add multiple include directories from a txt file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, include-path

I have a text file with many many paths that need to be added to: **Additional Include Directories**. 
Is there a possibility to copy all of them at once or include them directly from a txt file?

I have seen this SO post: [Recursive Include Paths in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353903/recursive-include-paths-in-visual-studio-2015?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Which suggest a syntax such as:
/I "MY_PATH/TO/INCLUDE/DIR"

and then use: **@IncludeDirs.txt** to the **Additional Include Directories**. But it does not seem to work for me. I placed the txt file in the root folder of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up is formatting my path from the text file with semicolons on line breaks and adding the include directories directly into the .vxproj file:

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  ..\..\some\dir;
  ..\another\dir;
  ...
</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

Same also works for linking libs:

```
<AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
  ...
</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
<AdditionalDependencies>
  some_library.lib;
  another.lib;
  ...
</AdditionalDependencies>
```